# Multiple process curl command for urls to output to individual files

Tags: linux, bash, curl, xargs

I am attempting to curl multiple urls in a bash command. Eventually I will be curling a large number of Urls so I am using xargs to use multiple processes to speed up the process.
My file consists of x number of URLs:

```
https://someurl.com
https://someotherurl.com
```

My issue comes when attempting to output the results to separate files named after the URLs I curl.
The bash command I have is:

```
xargs -P 5 -n 1 -I% curl -k -L % -0 % < urls.txt
```

When I run this I get 'Failed to create file https://someotherurl.com'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a file with `/` in the filename.  You could do it this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "LINE: $line"

    if [[ "$line" != "" ]]
    then
        filename="${line#https://}"
        echo "FILENAME: $filename"
        
        # YOUR CURL COMMAND HERE, USING $filename
    fi
done < url.txt
```

- it ignores empty lines
- variable substitution is used to remove the `https://` part of each URL
- this will allow you to create the file

---

**Note**: if your URLs containt sub-directories, they must be removed as well.

Ex: you want to do `https://www.exemple.com/some/sub/dir`
The script I suggested here would try to create a file named "www.exemple.com/some/sub/dir".  In this case, you could replace the `/` with `_` using tr.

The script would become:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "LINE: $line"

    if [[ "$line" != "" ]]
    then
        filename=$(echo "$line" | tr '/' '_')
        filename2=${filename#https:__}
        echo "FILENAME: $filename2"

        # YOUR CURL COMMAND HERE, USING $filename2
    fi
done < url.txt
```

Comment: How would this work with xargs? If I put xargs in the curl command here, it will still only curl one URL at a time

Comment: ah, just noticed the `-P 5` argument to your `xargs`.  You could send the curl commands to background (&) to get many running in parallel.  To limit the number of `curl` running, you could implement a counter to pause the loop until a couple are done.  Or use `GNU parallel`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use GNU Parallel due to restrictions.
Yea the xargs is the bit I am especially struggling with, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because your question is ambiguous, I would assume:

1. You have a file `urls.txt` that contains URLs separated by `LF`.
2. You want to download all URLs by `curl` and use each URL as its filename.

Unfortunately, that's not possible because URL contains invalid characters like slash `/`. Alternatively, for this case, I would suggest you use Bsse64 safe mode to decode URL before saving to file based on [RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548#section-4).

After applying this requirement, your script would become like:

```sh
seq 100 | xargs -I@ echo 'https://example.com?@' > urls.txt
xargs -P0 -L1 sh -c 'curl -SskL0 -o $(printf %s "$1" | uuencode -m /dev/stdout | sed "1d;\$d" | tr +/ -_) "$1"' sh < urls.txt
```